# Capturing a RAW8 video stream from a camera

Tags: stream, directshow, video-capture, image-formats

I've a camera that has a RAW8 stream, Bayer pattern:

```
                                  B  Gr B  Gr...
                                  Gr R  Gr R...
```

Can I capture the stream with DirectShow Sample Grabber Filter?
If not are there any other API I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can if the camera is DirectShow compatible. In which case you will be able to see it as an option in GraphEdit under video capture devices, and you will also be able to inspect media types the camera advertises.

Comment: I see the camera in graphedit, but I can't retrieve the stream
I tried Render Pin option, but all the frames arrive as black.
I am sure that the camera works because I have a software that captures the video, but I have no idea what API it uses.
In addition, I know for sure it's RAW8 stream

Comment: You can check if this third party app uses DirectShow with http://alax.info/blog/1430 Blackness might be caused by bad decoder. If you have the frames (even black), you should be able to capture. Other than DriectShow, it might be only vendor specific API.